# How to write a custom feeder for gatling json?

Tags: json, gatling

I have a `jsonurl` which I want to read and it looks like this:

```
> {
>     "elements": [
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 0,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 186,
>           "height": 10.526316
>         },
>         "type": "Header"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 0,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 0,
>           "height": 0
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 0,
>           "y": 14.035088,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 3.508772
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 95.08772,
>           "y": 14.035088,
>           "width": 90.87719,
>           "height": 45.614037
>         },
>         "type": "Image"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 95.08772,
>           "y": 63.157894,
>           "width": 90.87719,
>           "height": 3.508772
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 95.08772,
>           "y": 63.157894,
>           "width": 90.87719,
>           "height": 3.508772
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 47.54386,
>           "y": 42.105263,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 5.9649124
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 0,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 98.24561
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 47.54386,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 98.24561
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 95.08772,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 98.24561
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       },
>       {
>         "box": {
>           "x": 142.63158,
>           "y": 0,
>           "width": 43.333332,
>           "height": 98.24561
>         },
>         "type": "Regular"
>       }
>     ],
>     "points": [
>       {
>         "x": 190,
>         "y": 22.192982
>       },
>       {
>         "x": 376,
>         "y": 22.192982
>       },
>       {
>         "x": 376,
>         "y": 120.4386
>       },
>       {
>         "x": 190,
>         "y": 120.4386
>       }
>     ],
>     "state": "UNUSED",
>     "contentPath": "/content/ffx/print-authoring/en/newsholes/FNZ/DPT/2016/05/30/test_pages/q001/newshole-63019301",
>     "assetId": null   },
```

I then want to read the `"state"` and `"contentPath"` and map them.
currently I am using a static source like:

> val nhfeeder = jsonFile("shapes-data.json")

using as,

> .feed(nhfeeder)

which is a static source so I want a custom feeder which can read directly from the `jsonurl` and do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Gatling documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.3/session/feeder.html?highlight=feeder) you can find solution in 'JSON feeders' section

```
val jsonUrlFeeder = jsonUrl("http://me.com/foo.json")
```

Comment: this is not a very useful answer and also generic and besides the point

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change is to make your JSON's Root element be an Array.
Failure to do so will result in:#

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root element of JSON feeder file isn't an array`

Your JSON Structure should be:

```
[ 
    {"box": {
       "x": 0,
       "y": 0,
       "width": 186,
       "height": 10.526316
     },
     "type": "Header"
    },
    {
     "box": {
       "x": 0,
       "y": 0,
       "width": 0,
       "height": 0
     },
     "type": "Regular"
    },
    {
     "box": {
       "x": 0,
       "y": 14.035088,
       "width": 43.333332,
       "height": 3.508772
     },
     "type": "Regular"
    }
]
```

From this point on, when you create your Feeder:

```
val nhfeeder = jsonUrl("http://url-to-json/shapes-data.json").records
```

you now have a feeder that will provide values when used in session Expressions like:

```
scenario("my-scenario")
.foreach(nhfeeder, "shape", "index") {
 exec(
  http("calculate-for-shape-{index}")
  .get("/calculate-area/${shape.box.width}/${shape.box.height}")
 )}
```

I imagined a scenario where you want to test a function that calculates the area of your shapes. The important part here is that you can use Expression Language to navigate through the records aka. Json Object inside your Json Array.